# What macro fragment specifier should I use to match a method declaration when using a macro to define a trait?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to define a trait using a macro.

I've not found a fragment specifier that match a method declaration and 
the best I managed to get is the following:

```
macro_rules! decorated_trait (
    ($tid:ident {
        $( fn $b:ident($($args:expr),*) );*
    }) => {
        trait $tid {
            fn default_function(&self, _x: i32, _y: &str) {
            }

            $( fn $b( $( $args ),* ); )*
        }
    };
);

decorated_trait!(MyTrait { 
    fn my_function(&self, x: i32);
    fn another(&self)
});

struct Foo {}

impl MyTrait for Foo {

    fn my_function(&self) {
        self.default_function(1, "bar");
    }

    fn another(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let _foo = Foo{};
}
```

And the error is:

```
error: expected type, found `&self`
  --> src/main.rs:11:26
   |
11 |               $( fn $b( $( $args ),* ); )*
   |                            ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst it's technically possible to properly match the arguments of a trait method... it's not worth the hassle.  Just match them as raw tokens:

```
macro_rules! decorated_trait (
    ($tid:ident {
        $( fn $b:ident($($args:tt)*) );*
    }) => {
        trait $tid {
            fn default_function(&self, _x: i32, _y: &str) {
            }

            $( fn $b( $( $args )* ); )*
        }
    };
);
```

The reason your macro doesn't work is that arguments are not types.  They are a single optional "`self`-ish" argument that can take several different forms, followed by zero or more `pattern: type` pairs, except where they don't have a pattern.

Like I said, not worth the hassle.

Comment: Many thanks @DK. Just to be sure ... I understand your explanation as: an `expr` evaluate to a value and has a type, but `&self` and function arguments are not expressions. Is it right?

Comment: The `self` argument is special and isn't anything specific that you can directly match.  The other arguments are combinations of patterns and types.  So no, they're not expressions.